# Contour Plot not taking previously defined expressions?

Tags: plotting, functions

I am new to *Mathematica* so my question might sound a bit silly, but I hope you help me.

While learning `ContourPlot`, I have learned that when I use the previously defined expressions as inputs onto it, it doesn't seem to work, and only putting them in manually seems to work.

For example, defining

```
f1 = x^2/9 + y^2/4 == 1
f2 = x^2 - 1 == y
```

and then evaluating

```
ContourPlot[{f1, f2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 8}]
```

results in empty plot, while putting the expressions manually inside such as

```
ContourPlot[{x^2/9 + y^2/4 == 1, x^2 - 1 == y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 8}]
```

results in what I want...

What's more is, this also seems to occur when using `NSolve`... Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the `HoldAll` attribute of `ContourPlot`... It works with `ContourPlot[Evaluate[{f1, f2}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 8}]`.

Comment: Thank you! Could you specify what you mean by that?

Comment: @DannyHan As @MelaGo noted, `ContourPlot` has attribute `HoldAll`. Before evaluating anything (in particular, before inserting the definitions of `f1` and `f2`), `ContourPlot` will look at the first argument and decide what type of plot you want - whether you're giving it a single curve or a list and whether you are giving it a function or an equation. (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) Here, it sees `{f1, f2}` and decides to plot two functions. When it starts evaluating `f1` and `f2` for given `x` and `y`, it doesn't get a number, but `True` and `False`, so it doesn't plot anything (non-numerical results are simply ignored by all/most plotting functions). `Evaluate` forces evaluation to occur before `ContourPlot`, so `ContourPlot` sees a list of equations, which it can then correctly plot.

Comment: @LukasLang Great explanation! Worth posting as an answer.

Comment: @DannyHan With `NSolve` you shouldn't observe such behavior because it doesn't have a `Hold*` attribute. If you do observe something strange, please create a separate question on it (or at least add an example to this question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>As suggested, I'm expanding my comment into an answer</sub>

The problem here is the [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute of [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html). Like `Plot` and similar functions the process goes something like this:

- Look at the first argument, and decide what form it has:

  - If it's a list, the user wants to plot multiple functions
  - If it's an equation with `==`, the user wants to plot the solution to that equation
- Start the evaluation at different points (this part is done recursively on many points)

  - Set the values of the variables (second and third argument) to the correct values (similar to [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), as noted in the details section of [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html))
  - Evaluate the first argument and use the result

Now we see what the problem in your case is:

```
ContourPlot[{f1, f2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 8}]
```

When `ContourPlot` decides on the type of plot you want, it decides on "plot contours for two functions", since all it sees at that point is `{f1, f2}`. Now, values like e.g. `x=0`,`y=0` are assigned and `f1`,`f2` are evaluated. The problem is that this results in e.g.

```
          {f1, f2}
(* --> *) {x^2/9 + y^2/4 == 1,x^2 - 1 == y}
(* --> *) {0^2/9 + 0^2/4 == 1,0^2 - 1 == 0}
(* --> *) {0 == 1,- 1 == 0}
(* --> *) {False, False}
```

And like most plotting functions, non-numeric results (like the `False` above, are simply discarded).

It is now also clear why [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) fixes the issue: It forces the first argument of `ContourPlot` to be evaluated before `ContourPlot` has a chance to look at it. So now the evaluation sequence goes like this:

```
          ContourPlot[Evaluate[{f1, f2}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 8}]
(* --> *) ContourPlot[{x^2/9 + y^2/4 == 1,x^2 - 1 == y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 8}]
```

At this point `ContourPlot` examines the first argument and decides on "plot the solutions of two equations", which is what we want.

It should be noted that the only thing that `ContourPlot` needs to see are the lists (when multiple things are to be plotted) and the equations - everything else can be evaluated later. This means the following will also work:

```
g1 = x^2/9 + y^2/4
g2 = x^2 - 1

ContourPlot[{g1 == 1, g2 == y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 8}]
```

### TL;DR;

To summarise, force evaluation of the first argument of `ContourPlot` using `Evaluate` to ensure that the right type of plot is chosen:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[{f1, f2}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: OMG thank you so much! Now I understand :)